# Result source current hub site token

Tags: search, search-scope, result-source

Is there a way from with a custom result source to target a hub site? Returning results contained in any of the sites in that hub?
I’m hoping there is a token, similar to {Site}

Much like the modern web parts allow you to select ‘Sites in the hub’

How can I do in a custom result source?

Comment: I think you need to rephrase that question to make it more clear.

Comment: Agreed, it was a bit of a Sunday ramble.  Edited.